# ProfileCommon not found in ProfileModule.MigrateAnonymous Event in WebApplication Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, profile, anonymous

I am designing an online store.
Currently I am using AspNetSqlProfileProvider & Simple Form authentication to implement my Cart which works completely fine!

But the problem occurs while the anonymous user signs up and a new profile is created. Then the old cart content (as anonymous user) is not migrated into the new profile.

Based on this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.profile.profilemodule.migrateanonymous(v=vs.110).aspx) I used **Profile_OnMigrateAnonymous** event in global.asax in order to transfer Profile Data from the Anonymous User Profile to The Registered User Profile.

As I searched for this issue I found that CommonProfile is not accessible within the Web Applications, so I cannot use **Profile.GetProfile(args.AnonymousID)**

Besides, I don't want to use ASP.NET MembershipProvider.

So, how am I supposed to get data from AnonymousID?

Comment: can anyone help me? i want to transfer profile data of anonymous user to registered user, profile content have shopping cart of user, so after registration all items in basket is empty

Comment: Hi Did you manage to sort this issue ?, I am working on this issue and no luck so far, appreciate if you could share your resolution if you were to resolve the issue ,